# How to add mass file extensions?

Tags: files, music, xbmc

I am trying to setup my XBMC music and used a program called puddletag to organize all the filenames and ID3 tags.  The problem is puddletag erased all the file extensions and now XBMC won't recognize the files as music.  I need to add .mp3 to all 1000 of my music files.  I realize I can simply rename them with the extension included but I didn't know if there was a way through Ubuntu or puddletag (if someone is familiar) to do this to all selected files.

Comment: `for file in *; do mv $file "$file.mp3"; done`

Comment: Do I need to just be in my Music directory in terminal and type this?

Comment: yes but if only all the files in your dir are all mp3. it will not work on subdirs.

Comment: I just tried it but this is the output it gave me for each file in terminal. mv: target ‘Ludo - Hum Along.mp3’ is not a directory

Comment: what's your command again?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, I copied and pasted the command you gave and ran that inside the Music directory with terminal.

Comment: `yes but if only all the files in your dir are all mp3. it will not work on subdirs`

Comment: micah@micah-desktop:~/Test$ for file in *; do mv $file "$file.mp3"; done
mv: target ‘3Oh!3 - See You Go.mp3’ is not a directory
mv: target ‘3Oh!3 - Starstrukk.mp3.mp3’ is not a directory
mv: target ‘3Oh!3 - Still Around.mp3’ is not a directory
mv: target ‘3Oh!3 - Streets Of Gold.mp3’ is not a directory
mv: target ‘3Oh!3 - Tapp.mp3’ is not a directory
This is not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  Go to that directory and enter this code.  It will place .mp3 after everything regardless if it's an mp3 or not.

```
find . -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.mp3 \;
```